# How to get starting with Linear programming and Python?

Tags: python, resources, linear-algebra

Any resources to learn Python and using Python to learn linear programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at that time the Harvard Edu can be provided free python course. this is best time to learn python. I hope this link helps you...

https://online-learning.harvard.edu/catalog?keywords=&paid%5B1%5D=1&max_price=&start_date_range%5Bmin%5D%5Bdate%5D=&start_date_range%5Bmax%5D%5Bdate%5D=

Answer (score 0):

I found it very helpful to get started with PuLP.
Following two links provide a basic insight into the topic IMO:

https://towardsdatascience.com/linear-programming-and-discrete-optimization-with-python-using-pulp-449f3c5f6e99

and

https://hackernoon.com/linear-programming-in-python-a-straight-forward-tutorial-a0d152618121